# Can we say "Three times, I hit my head on this lamp" to mean "I hit my head on this lamp three times"?

Tags: word-order

Can we say

> **"Three times, I hit my head on this lamp."**
>
> **"Many times, I hit my head on this lamp."**
>
> **"Twice, I hit my head on this lamp."**

etc.

to mean

> **"I hit my head on this lamp three times."**
>
> **"I hit my head on this lamp many times."**
>
> **"I hit my head on this lamp twice."**

etc.?

**Context:** Let's say there is a friend of mine in my room and I am talking about how many times I hit my head on the room's lamp in the past.

**My opinion:** I think we can use *"one time"* or *"once"* at the beginnings of these kind of sentences, but I am not sure about the phrases like the ones I gave in the example sentences.

Comment: Why do you think that you might not be able to use those phrases at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV They just sounded unusual to me.

Comment: You could use the word - bumped.  I bumped into this lamp three times today.

Comment: @lea Thank you. Do you think it is wrong to use those phrases at the beginning?

Comment: I was not sure if there were any mistakes in the sentences. So I suggested an alternative.